# traversing a grid up or down without having to write the same loop twice

Tags: rust

I'm working on moving in a vector that acts as a representation of a 2d grid, and I want to be able to move straight up or down, but don't want to rewrite the for loop twice. I came up with this solution that fails due to the borrow checker when indexing into the grid.

```rs
// fill the vec later
let grid: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(WIDTH*HEIGHT);
let mut current_position = Point::new(somewhere);
let end = Point::new(somewhere_else);
let moving: &mut usize;
let to: u32;

if moving_horizontal {
    moving = &mut current_position.x;
    to = end.x;
}
else {
    moving = &mut current_position.y;
    to = end.y;
}

for _ in *moving..=to {
    // do stuff with this
    grid[current_position.x+current_position.y*HEIGHT];
    *moving += 1;
}
```

Is there any neat solution to this or do I have to just write the same for loop twice in each block of my conditional statements?

Comment: where do `current.x` and `current.y` come from?

Comment: @user1984 that was a typo when pasting, `current` is meant to be `current_position` I'll edit it.

Comment: What is `grid`? `Vec<u8>`? `Vec<Vec<u8>>`? `[[u8]]`? Also your for loop increments `moving` on each iteration, you don't need to manually increment it.

Comment: Assuming (x=0, y=0) is the top left and you're using actual 2d indexing: you can use arithmetic to move your grid. x+1 moves right one, x-1 moves left one, y-1 moves up one, y+1 moves down one. You can make a move method that can move in any direction by taking a relative x and y value, and just add them to your current coordinates.

Comment: @MeetTitan I thought it being a 1 dimensional plain vec could be inferred from the code but I added it explicitly for clarity.

Comment: As far as indexing goes, yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. And I do need to increment `moving`as far as I know because it is in a range, not being incremented on its own, but you're totally right about the addition. Thank you

Comment: @MeetTitan I glanced over your comment and without thinking about it I thought it would work, but in reality it wouldn't. The whole purpose of this thread is trying to make a generic loop that increments along the axis we're moving on without having to write two separate loops for each axis and using explicit addition to an axis would not allow this.

Comment: Is something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b1085699b34d0e440263564ab3b25c1) what you mean, or do I misunderstand entirely?

Comment: @MeetTitan no this wouldn't do. I'm aware I can just directly add to a point and get to where I want to be, but the aim is to give two coordinates and operate on each individual point in the line that lies between, so just jumping from one to the other wouldnt work. What I was trying to do here would allow for it to move in the x axis or the y axis in 1 loop without it having to know which axis is which by just aliasing it to "moving" and "still" axis

Comment: Get your start point and your end point, find the slope, and iterate on the points lying on the line from start to end. This should work in any direction, including diagonally, with only one loop; assuming you're only moving in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't too harsh on me. I've just started a few days ago to learn Rust. This is just an idea I had and I'm posting it to learn if it works in this situation or not.

```rs
let mut current_position = Point::new(somewhere);
let end = Point::new(somewhere_else);
let moving: &mut usize;
let not_moving: &usize;
let to: u32;

if moving_horizontal {
    moving = &mut current_position.x;
    not_moving = &current_position.y;
    to = end.x
} else {
    moving = &mut current_position.y;
    not_moving = &current_position.x;
    to = end.y
}

for _ in *moving..=to {
    // do stuff with this

    if moving_horizontal {
        grid[*moving + *not_moving * HEIGHT];
    } else {
        grid[*not_moving + *moving * HEGHT];
    }
    *moving += 1;
}
```

If we didn't have to use `moving` in the `for` declaration, it could be written in a much better way, but I'm not sure about the details of the algorithm.

Anyway, even if this passes the borrow checker, it is very difficult to read and a double for loop would be much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to mutate the `current_position` so that it moves to the `end` Point horizontally or vertically.

```
fn main() {
    moving_position(true);
    moving_position(false);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}
impl Point {
    fn new(x: usize, y: usize) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
}

const WIDTH: usize = 30;
const HEIGHT: usize = 30;
fn moving_position(moving_horizontal: bool) {
    let grid: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(WIDTH * HEIGHT);
    let mut current_position = Point::new(8, 5);
    let end = Point::new(0, 1);
    println!("Starting at: {:?}", current_position);
    match moving_horizontal {
        true => move_horizontal(&mut current_position, end.x),
        false => move_vertical(&mut current_position, end.y),
    };
    println!("Final position: {:?}",current_position);
}

fn move_horizontal(current_position: &mut Point, to: usize) {
    match current_position.x <= to {
        true => for i in current_position.x+1..=to {
            current_position.x = i;
            println!("moving right: {:?}", current_position);
        },
        false => for i in (to..current_position.x).rev() {
            current_position.x = i;
            println!("moving left: {:?}", current_position);
        },
    };
}

fn move_vertical(mut current_position: &mut Point, to: usize) {    
    match current_position.y <= to {
        true => for i in current_position.y+1..=to {
            current_position.y = i;
            println!("moving up: {:?}", current_position);
        },
        false => for i in (to..current_position.y).rev() {
            current_position.y = i;
            println!("moving down: {:?}", current_position);
        },
    };
}
```

We check if its `moving_horizontal` and depending on that we call functions `move_horizontal` or `move_vertical`.
These two functions take the current_position as a mutable reference (meaning we will mutate current_position in the function but will return ownership).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=976a43c667191cf4e4da2cb3e87c457d)

Comment: I'm confused as to how this would work, in the example code if rust's borrow checker allowed it compile then `*moving += 1` would be changing the value of either `current_position.x` or `current_position.y`, which would then modify what index we're accessing. As far as I can see and understand your solution doesn't modify that therefor the index is never changed and we never actually move.

Comment: Aah, I think I understand what you are trying to do now.  You want the current_position to move to the end position in the loop right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate all the move steps first and then change the current point with the steps one by one in one single loop.

There are four kinds of steps -- (-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) and (0, -1), corresponding to moving left, right, up and down. You can calculate how many steps are needed and which direction needs to be taken first based on the relative positions of the `curr` and `end` points and the `moving_horizontal` flag.

```
use std::iter::repeat;

struct Point {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

fn main() {
    const HEIGHT: usize = 25;
    const WIDTH: usize = 80;
    
    const LEFT: (i8, i8) = (-1, 0);
    const RIGHT: (i8, i8) = (1, 0);
    const UP: (i8, i8) = (0, 1);
    const DOWN: (i8, i8) = (0, -1);
    
    let grid: Vec<u8> = vec![0; WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    let mut curr = Point {x: 6, y: 2 };
    let end = Point {x: 3, y: 4 };

    let (x_step, x_num) = if end.x > curr.x { (RIGHT, end.x - curr.x) }
                          else { (LEFT, curr.x - end.x) };

    let (y_step, y_num) = if end.y > curr.y { (UP, end.y - curr.y) }
                          else { (DOWN, curr.y - end.y) };

    let moving_horizontal = true;
    let all_steps = if moving_horizontal {
        repeat(x_step).take(x_num).chain(repeat(y_step).take(y_num))
    } else {
        repeat(y_step).take(y_num).chain(repeat(x_step).take(x_num))
    };

    println!("Start: (x:{}, y:{})", curr.x, curr.y);
    println!("End: (x:{}, y:{})", end.x, end.y);
    println!("Steps (Horizontal: {}):", moving_horizontal);
    for (i, step) in all_steps.enumerate() {
        // do stuff with this
        grid[curr.x + curr.y * HEIGHT];

        curr.x = match step.0 {
            1 => curr.x + 1,
            -1 => curr.x - 1,
            _ => curr.x
        };

        curr.y = match step.1 {
            1 => curr.y + 1,
            -1 => curr.y -1,
            _ => curr.y
        };

        println!("{} => (x:{}, y:{})", i, curr.x, curr.y);

    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db6c44bfe9c0abd414c027a9c9988b44)

The output when `moving_horizontal` is `true`:

```
Start: (x:6, y:2)
End: (x:3, y:4)
Steps (Horizontal: true):
0 => (x:5, y:2)
1 => (x:4, y:2)
2 => (x:3, y:2)
3 => (x:3, y:3)
4 => (x:3, y:4)
```

The output when `moving_horizontal` is `false`:

```
Start: (x:6, y:2)
End: (x:3, y:4)
Steps (Horizontal: false):
0 => (x:6, y:3)
1 => (x:6, y:4)
2 => (x:5, y:4)
3 => (x:4, y:4)
4 => (x:3, y:4)
```